# sql-запрос агрегированных данных таблицы по месяцам

Tags: sql, sql-server

Здравствуйте. Объясню, что мне нужно, на примере. Дана таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужен такой запрос, чтобы получилось следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть мне нужен столбец количества пользователей, у которых совпадает сайт магазина, продукт и месяц покупки. Если я правильно понимаю, GROUP BY выводит совпадение по дням, а мне надо по месяцам. Чувствую, что ответ на поверхности, нуждаюсь в вашей помощи.

Comment: значит надо дату привести к месяцу, фукнциями year и month, например

Comment: А по какому принципу выбран "день покупки" из нескольких для группы? и какой вообще смысл выводить ДЕНЬ, группируя по МЕСЯЦУ?

Comment: Как вывести от даты только месяц и год? Глупый вопрос, но всё же

Comment: `DatePart(m, [День покупки]) - месяц;
    DatePart(y, [День покупки]) - год`

Answer (score 1):

Если вы не справляетесь сразу со сложным запросом - попробуйте разбить проблему на несколько частей и решать их по очереди. Для начала, определить, как именно получить месяц из даты.
Понятно, что просто извлечь месяц недостаточно, т.к. месяц этого года будет равен месяцу прошлого, а это, по всей видимости, не то, чего вы хотите. Как добавить год, вам подсказали в комментариях.

После того, как получили правильный месяц, делайте группировку.

Если я правильно понял, какого результата вы пытаетесь добиться, предполагаю, что ваш итоговый запрос будет выглядеть так:

```
select [Сайт магазина]
     , [Продукт]
     , cast(year([День покупки]) as varchar(10)) + 
       '-' + 
       cast(month([День покупки]) as varchar(10)) as [Месяц покупки]
     , count(distinct [Имя пользователя]) as [Количество аккаунтов]
from [Таблица]
group by [Сайт магазина]
       , [Продукт]
       , cast(year([День покупки]) as varchar(10)) + 
         '-' + 
         cast(month([День покупки]) as varchar(10))
```